# SSH connection to know host still needs authorization

Tags: ssh, duplicity, duply

I am trying to setup a backup server using `duply` and a secure connection.

I have created the `~/.ssh/config` file with the following content:

```
Host backup
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_backup
  Hostname <server_ip>
  Port 22
  User <user_on_host>
```

Furthermore, I have also defined the `known_hosts` file, by copy-pasting in it the server public key (found in `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub`)

All seems to work properly when using the `ssh -v backup` command:

```
Authenticated to <server_ip> ([<server_ip>]:22)
```

However, when launching `duply` backup routine, I see that the server is not recognized:

```
The authenticity of host '[<server_ip>]:22' can't be established.
SSH-ED25519 key fingerprint is c3:06:95:f8:5f:d3:76:7f:c6:9d:19:ef:e5:23:9a:14.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Why is this happening?

---

**Update**

It seems that `duply` is computing the MD5 hash of the public key, while `ssh` the SHA256 one: in fact, as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1088165/get-ssh-key-fingerprint-in-old-hex-format-on-new-version-of-openssh/1088260), `ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub` returns the same hexadecimal stated above. Since they are two different hash of the same key, why a connection confirmation is still asked? Is it possible to oblige SSH to use only a single hash algorithm?

**Further update:**

`ssh -o FingerprintHash=md5 -v backup` does not require confirmation, so I suppose that the issue is limited to `duply`. Maybe, does it not refer to the user `known_hosts` file?

Comment: My guess is that the line in `known_hosts` is for a server named `backup`. If so, try adding a line with the same public hostkey for `<server_ip>`.

Comment: @berndbausch, in `known_hosts` I have the server IP hashed, key type and value. I have added all the public keys of the server (ssh-dss, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ssh-ed25519 and ssh-rsa) but it is still stated as unknown.

Comment: Then I would double-check the fingerprint of the key that you entered in `known_hosts`. The command is `ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub`. Also, more verbosity (`ssh -vvv`) should show you how the SSH client cycles through the content of `known_hosts`; perhaps that reveals something.

Comment: @berndbausch, using the command you suggested, I probably found the source of the issue and so I updated the question.

Comment: I am not familiar with `duply`, but having a quick look at the source, it seems to come with its own profiles, so potentially it doesn't even look at the `~/.ssh/config` you created. So I guess you'll need to have a closer look at `duply` configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`duply` is built upon the Paramiko python module and checking more in depth its implementation, it seems that Paramiko is not able to manage hashed known hosts.
I have then modified the SSH configuration file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` by setting `HashKnownHosts no`, and rewritten the content of `~/.ssh/known_hosts` by inserting in clear target IPs and/or domains.